# Bash script for retrieving server stats

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

printf "Date\tMemory"

end=$((SECONDS+3600))

while[$SECONDS -lt $end];do

Memory=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2 {printf "%.2f%%\t",$3*200/$2')

Date=$(date"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

echo "$Date $Memory"

sleep 15

done
```

Q1: I have written above code and saved in `perfMemstats.sh` file and executed it using below command:

```
bash perfMemstats.sh >> perfStats.dat
```

Problem :

1. If I execute this `.sh` file its executed only for 10 mins. I want to run this file in background so that I can monitor other stats. Please let me know what mistake I'm doing. I even tried giving '&' it running in background but only for 10 min.
2. If I run this command without saving it in an output file (`bash perfMemstats.sh`) it is executing for 1 hour.

Comment: Do you mean that the following command _terminates_ after 10 minutes: `bash perfMemstats.sh >> perfStats.dat`?

Comment: Yes. It's getting terminated

Comment: Try to use the tee command like "bash perfMemstats.sh | tee -a perfStats.dat". Does it run over 10min?

Comment: Tried this, But the output is not saving in .day file.

Comment: If I run the bash script without saving the output in day file it is executing for 1 hour. But if I try to save the output then I'm facing issue. It's not executing more than 10 mins

Comment: Put your code in here: https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the `while` line.